# Can I hire a mobility scooter in Dortmund?

Tags: germany, accessibility

I am trying to find mobility scooter hire in Dortmund in Germany, do you know of any?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's possible. I found at least one company that is renting mobility scooters.

On [their website](https://www.tingelhoff.de/hilfsmittel-miete) (only in German) you can find the pricelist (under Elektromobil / Scooter 6km/h). You can pick it up, but they also offer a delivery.

This kind of medical stores are called in German *Sanitätshaus* You can search for it and probably find other stores in Dortmund that are renting scooters.